# Laravel Response method not allowed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, response, laravel-response

Im using this code from the current Laravel documentation

```
return redirect()->action(
    'UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]
);
```

And changed it to my own controller like this:

```
return redirect()->action('ProjectController@showProject',['id'=> 2]);
```

My route: `Route::get('/crm/project/{id}', 'ProjectController@showProject');`

According to my `F12` this is my request url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/back/crm/project/2` Which is correct. But im getting the following error: `405 Method Not Allowed`.

This is the start of my stacktrace:

> {message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",…}

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added route.

Comment: can you show your route

Comment: `Route::get('/crm/project/{id}', 'ProjectController@showProject');` is my route.

Comment: what you found url after rediract where you get this erro

Comment: What? @ShaielndraGupta I find this error if I go to my `Inspect Element->network->Preview/Headers/Respone`

Comment: I am talking about your request URL where you getting the error.You can fount it in inspect->network and and view the headers

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/back/crm/project/2`. stated this in my post aswell.

Comment: can you do `php artisan route:list` in your terminal and share your route results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186940/discussion-between-armando-van-oeffelen-and-shaielndra-gupta).

Comment: Can you post your showProject method?

Answer (score 0):

Redirections are always made using `GET` method. I assume in `web.php` you have this route defined using other HTTP method (for example `PUT` or `POST`) - that's why you are getting this error. Take a look at `web.php` file and make sure you are using `GET` method or make redirection to other url.

Comment: Im using the `GET` method on my route where i want to redirect to. Or do i have to use it on a `GET` route aswell? Because the Route im currently on is a `PUT` route..

Route i want to redirect to : `Route::get('/crm/project/{id}', 'ProjectController@showProject');`

Route currently on : `Route::put('/crm/project/{id}', 'ProjectController@update');`

Answer (score 0):

This can be a tricky one.

I think you will need to change the method. Check your web.php for a declration for that route. also it is better to use a middleware group for your route.

This is simply sayng that your methode is not allowed caouse it has been declared with an another method.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are getting because you have used the same function name for tow different methods one for get and one for put that why you are getting the error because you are passing action in redirect so its search for action and found that action with put method

use this for redirect

```
return redirect()->route('/back/crm/project/', ['id' => 1]);
```

> One more thing i want to suggest you never use the rediraction in
>   ajax request its not a good programing practises 
>   and it'll not work at all if you have put or post method in your ajax

make a succes response and refresh your location thats it